# I am trying to figure out how to increment and decrement the values with Django but I get this error cannot unpack non-iterable ModelBase object

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

Hi there I am having an issue incrementing and decrement a value in the views.py file in my application, also I am getting the error of "cannot unpack non-iterable ModelBase object" Everything else works beside the increment and decrement function. As soon as I press the increment or the decrement button it does not work and it spits that error out. Also I will post the view.py file, the html file, and the urls just so there can be more context.

> the views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest
from .models import Habit
# Create your views here.

def list_habit_items(request):
    context = {'habit_list':Habit.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'habits/habit_list.html',context)

def insert_habit_item(request:HttpRequest):
    habit=Habit(IndHabit =request.POST['habit'])
    habit.save()
    return redirect('/habits/list/')

def delete_habit_item(request,habit_id):
    habit_to_delete = Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)
    habit_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/habits/list/')
    
def increment_habit_value(request,habit_id):
    habit_to_increment = Habit.objects.get(Habit,id=habit_id)
    habit_to_increment.values += 1
    habit_to_increment.save(['values'])
    return redirect('/habits/list/')

def decrement_habit_value(request,habit_id):
    habit_to_decrement = Habit.objects.get(Habit,id=habit_id)
    habit_to_decrement.values -= 1
    habit_to_decrement.save(['values'])
    return redirect('/habits/list/')
```

> the models

```
class Habit(models.Model):
#this makes a attribute that describes the individual Habit
#the individual Habit and Value.
    IndHabit=models.TextField()
   
    IndValue=models.IntegerField()
```

> the urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns=[
    path('list/',views.list_habit_items),
    path('insert_habit/',views.insert_habit_item,name='insert_habit_item'),
    path('delete_habit/<int:habit_id>',views.delete_habit_item,name='delete_habit_item'),
    path('increment_habit/<int:habit_id>',views.increment_habit_value,name='increment_habit_value'),
    path('decrement_habit/<int:habit_id>',views.decrement_habit_value,name='decrement_habit_value'),
    ]
```

> the html file

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'habits/styles.css' %} " />
        <title>Habit</title>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-light">
        <!--good-->
        <div class="container">
            <!--good-->
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <!--good-->
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                    <!--good-->
                    <div class="card">
                        <!--good-->
                        <div class="card-header shadow-sm bg-white">
                            <h1 class="display-5 text-info">
                                Habits <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt" style="color: red"></i>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <form
                                            action="{% url 'insert_habit_item'%}"
                                            method="post"
                                            autocomplete="off"
                                        >
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <!--  value used by server to make sure if the post or response is from 
                                        a trusted source or not -->
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="habit" />
                                                <div class="input-group-append text-info">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text bg-white py-0"
                                                        ><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm text-info">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    {% for habit in habit_list %}
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        {{habit.IndHabit}}
                                        <form
                                            action="{% url 'decrement_habit_value' habit.id %}"
                                            method="post"
                                            class="float-right d-inline"
                                        >
                                            {% csrf_token %}

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                                <i
                                                    class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                ></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                        {{habit.IndValue}}
                                        <form
                                            action="{% url 'increment_habit_value' habit.id %}"
                                            method="post"
                                            class="float-right d-inline"
                                        >
                                            {% csrf_token %}

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                                <i
                                                    class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                                ></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                        <form
                                            action="{% url 'delete_habit_item' habit.id %}"
                                            method="post"
                                            class="float-right d-inline"
                                        >
                                            {% csrf_token %}

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                                <i
                                                    class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"
                                                ></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    {% empty %}
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <span>No Habits Found!</span>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing the model as an argument here - `Habit.objects.get(Habit,id=habit_id)`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken about what I saw, there are three things here I'm seeing a problem with...

1. Where you're trying the get an `habit object`. You have `Habit.objects.get(Habit,id=habit_id)` when it should be `Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)`.
2. You're trying to increment and decrement a field that doesn't exist. You have `habit_to_increment.values += 1` when the model doesn't have a field called `values`. What should be there is `IndValue` according to what you've posted for your `Habit model`.
3. After incrementing or decrementing the `IndValue`, then you can just call the `save method` on the object without passing any value to it. What you have is `habit_to_increment.save(['values'])`, just use `habit_to_increment.save()`.

Another quick recommendation here is for you to set a default value to the `Habit` model IndValue field. `IndValue=models.IntegerField(default=0)`.

Ideally, this should work for you...

```
def increment_habit_value(request, habit_id):
     habit_to_increment = Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)
     habit_to_increment.IndValue += 1
     habit_to_increment.save()

     return redirect('/habits/list/')


def decrement_habit_value(request, habit_id):
     habit_to_decrement = Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)
     habit_to_decrement.IndValue -= 1
     habit_to_decrement.save()

     return redirect('/habits/list/')
```

Comment: Yes, thank you and I was actually looking of how to set the default value as well, that really helped and it worked!

Comment: I'm glad the solution solved multiple problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are referencing the field you want to increment won't work (or at least I've never seen it before). My guess is you are wanting to use .values()? Using [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) can be useful to convert a recordset into a dict, but there is no need to do that here, especially if you are simply altering a field then saving back to the database.

You just need the id value in your objects.get(), as the type of model is defined by Habit as in

```
habit_to_increment = Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)
```

However,I suspect you were wanting to use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)
which conveniently handles a bad id, and does require the Model as an argument, so I used it here

Try the following

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def increment_habit_value(request,habit_id):
    habit_to_increment = get_object_or_404(Habit, id=habit_id)
    #Because there is only one object, you can refer to the field you want to increment directly.
    habit_to_increment.IndValue += 1
    habit_to_increment.save()
    return redirect('/habits/list/')

#similarly with the decrement view
def decrement_habit_value(request, habit_id):
    habit_to_decrement = get_object_or_404(Habit, id=habit_id)
    habit_to_decrement.IndValue -= 1
    habit_to_decrement.save()
    return redirect('/habits/list/')
```

Comment: Oh I see I was using it wrong the whole entire time, thank you it worked!